# How do you filter out out a subset of results if it does not contain a desired date?

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, statistics, standard-deviation

I'm pulling data from MySQL server and performing an analysis to capture customer volume that falls two standard deviations away from the rolling mean. However, I do not care about performing this analysis on stores that do not have any customer volume on the date of interest. In this case the max date.

Is there away to filter out the StoreId's that do not have any volume on the desired date in SQL?

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE AS DATE), StoreId, COUNT(CustomerId) AS Customer_Volume
FROM CustomerTable
WHERE 1=1
      AND DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())
GROUP BY StoreId, CAST(DATE AS DATE)
ORDER BY 2,1
```

The data looks like:

```
Date       | StoreId | Customer_Volume
---------------------------------
2020-01-18 |     7   |    10
2020-01-19 |     7   |     8
2020-01-20 |     7   |     8
2020-01-21 |     7   |    12
2020-01-18 |    11   |     4
2020-01-19 |    11   |     2
```

So I'm wondering if there is away to filter out StoreId = 11 in this example case.

Comment: But the data that you want to filter out ***do*** have some Customer_Volume. I do not fully understand what do you want.

Comment: They do have Customer_Volume. But if they do not have the current date I do not care for any of those stores data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are one method:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE AS DATE), StoreId, COUNT(CustomerId) AS Customer_Volume
FROM CustomerTable
WHERE DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE()) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM CustomerTable ct
              WHERE ct2.StoreId = ct.StoreId AND
                    ct2.Date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
             )
GROUP BY StoreId, CAST(DATE AS DATE)
ORDER BY 2,1
```

Assuming the most recent date of interest is yesterday, you can use a correlated subquery to be sure that data is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with having the customer_volume

```
SELECT CAST(DATE AS DATE), StoreId, case when COUNT(CustomerId) AS Customer_Volume
FROM CustomerTable
WHERE 1=1
      AND DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())
GROUP BY StoreId, CAST(DATE AS DATE)
having COUNT(CustomerId)> 0
ORDER BY 2,1
```